# Sleep for x seconds before running next operation

Tags: asynchronous, f#, sleep

I have been trying in various ways to make my program sleep for 10 seconds before running the next line of code.

```
this.SetContentView (Resource_Layout.Main)  
let timer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000.0)
async{do timer.Start()}
this.SetContentView (Resource_Layout.next)
```

I can't get any solution to work.

Comment: Have you tried `Async.sleep`?

Comment: yeps. perhaps im not using it correctly. 'Async.Sleep(10000)' gives me type mismatch

Comment: http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/concurrency-async-and-parallel/

Comment: not helpful at all. Have been staring at that site for hours.

Comment: You're creating an async computation, but never actually starting it. So it never gets executed. `timer.Start` never happens.

Comment: Think of `async { ... }` as an expression like `seq { ... }`. It *creates* an Async object, but that object hasn't started running yet, just as `seq { 1..10 }` will create an IEnumerable, but that IEnumerable hasn't yet produced any values. This allows separation of concerns between creating the Async and running it, which can be done in two different functions or modules. That way, if you need to manipulate the Async object after creating it (say, by wrapping it in another `async` that handles exceptions and turns them into error values), you can do so. Starting the Async is an explicit step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `async` rather than the more direct way (of creating a timer and setting the content view in the event handler of the timer), then you need something like this:

```
this.SetContentView (Resource_Layout.Main)  
async{
   do! Async.Sleep(10000.0)
   this.SetContentView (Resource_Layout.next) }
|> Async.StartImmediate
```

The key points:

- Using `do! Async.Sleep` you can block the execution of asynchronous computation
- By moving the `SetContentView` call inside the `async`, it will happen after the sleep
- Using `Async.StartImmediate`, you start the workflow - and the sleeping ensures that the rest of the computation runs in the same threading context (meaning that it will run on the UI thread and the code will be able to access UI elements).